# Downloading Output files from Google Colabortory

Tags: google-colaboratory

For some reason I am not able to download my output files from colaboratory. I am able to upload input files but I can not download my output files separately. I am also using a mac.

Answer (score 0):

For information on various ways to download files from Colab, see https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb.